# ASP.NET Entity Framework - updating child dependencies with Attach

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Question on Entity Framework - I'm looking for more efficient way of updating a parent and child record.

Scenario - we have a parent object that contains one or many child objects. When the parent object gets updated, we need to clear out all the current child records and re-add new child records.

For example:

```
public bool UpdateProfile(Parent record)
{
        try
        {
            _context.Parent.Attach(record);       
            _context.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;

            List<Child> childrenToDelete = GetChildrenByParentId(parent.Id);
            foreach (Child child in childrenToDelete)
            {
                _context.Child.Remove(child);
                _context.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
            foreach (Child child in record.children)
            {
                _context.ProfileCategories.Add(child);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
}
        ...
    }
```

The code above throws an exception at the "_context.Parent.Attach(record)" line saying that there is a duplicate Ids of record. So our work around was:

```
public bool UpdateProfile(Parent record)
{
    try
    {
        var originalChildren = record.children;
        record.children = new List<Child>();
        _context.Parent.Attach(record);       
        _context.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        List<Child> childrenToDelete = GetChildrenByParentId(parent.Id);
        foreach (Child child in childrenToDelete)
        {
            _context.Child.Remove(child);
            _context.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        foreach (Child child in originalChildren)
        {
            _context.ProfileCategories.Add(child);
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
   }
   ...
}
```

This second block of code works, but i just feel its not ideal.

Could anyone tell us why the Attach is throwing the duplicate Id exception and if the solution we have is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I would shoot for something like this:

```
    public void UpdateProfile(Parent record)
    {
        using(var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var children = db.Children.Where(x => x.ParentId == record.Id);
            db.ProfileCategories.AddRange(children);
            db.Children.RemoveRange(children);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```